# Any way to make Xcode file 'tree' fonts bigger?

Tags: xcode, xcode7

I know how to change font color and size of editor screen in Xcode.

But any way to change font size at file tree?
(I use Xcode 7)

[image: font size of this tree]

Sometimes I feel the font size is too small...